# Program yourself or use data mining toolkit?

Tags: data-mining, software

I'm quite comfortable using Python and additional ML/Visualization packages for ML and data mining. How do the free data mining software RapidMinder, KNIME, etc. compare to this approach, and do they have a practical advantage over using ML libraries? Are these big software packages more than fancy drag-and-drop which slows you down if you have programming skills?

What is the approach of people who do serious data mining and who possess programming skills to choose? Do they prefer to write code?

Comment: What are you using it for?

Answer (score 1):

I think I agree, drag/drop approach for data mining is not want you need. I think you need something similar to Python-like scripting language. If you think about such approach to statistics, you can try [ScaVis program](http://jwork.org/scavis/) that use Python for statistics. Another option is SciPy or similar.